Boot failure after trying to install vmware on kubuntu 24.04
Hi guys I'm hoping perhaps someone can help me out. I am and have been running kubuntu 24.04 for quite some time. Over that time I have been working with virtualbox without any problems. However I just tried installing vmware workstation and that's when the problem started.
After a reboot my kubuntu won't load. I'm not getting any error message on the load screen it just hangs there after I enter my password. I can load system activity monitor and a terminal. But that's as far as I can get.
When I press Ctrl + alt and f4 I get the following messages
Failed to start system-machine.service - virtual machine and container registration service
Failed to start network manager. Service - network manager
. I'm typing this from my mobile phone.
Is this fixable or do I need to reinstall kubuntu.
Please help.
Quick edit. In the command when I type in nmcli general status I get the error
NetworkManager is not running.
Also when I opened the terminal and tried to sudo su it's telling me
Su: Authentication failure
I've tried booting the recovery mode and entering shell mode. It's looking for a password. I've tried my old and current ones but neither works.
